# Can't get parametric NDSolve to work for three ODE system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parametric-functions

Below is code to simulate a three ODE system. When running the code I get no errors put no output is empty as well. Because of the lack of errors I needed

**Code**

```
A = {{2, 5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1, mu}, {1, 0.5, 1}};
A // MatrixForm
tmax = 100;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
   x1'[t] == -(1 + x1[t]) (A[[1, 1]] x1[t] + A[[1, 2]] x2[t] + 
       A[[1, 3]] x3[t]),
   x2'[t] == -(1 + x2[t]) (A[[2, 1]] x1[t] + A[[2, 2]] x2[t] + 
       A[[2, 3]] x3[t]),
   x3'[t] == -(1 + x3[t]) (A[[3, 1]] x1[t] + A[[3, 2]] x2[t] + 
       A[[3, 3]] x3[t]),
   x1[0] == x10, x2[0] == x20, x3[0] == x30},
  {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, tmax}, {x10, x20, x30, mu}]

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x1[x10, x20, x30, mu], x2[x10, x20, x30, mu], 
     x3[x10, x20, x30, mu]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}], {{x10, 1, "x1"}, 
  0.01, 10}, {{x20, 1, "x2"}, 0.01, 10}, {{x30, 1, "x3"}, 0.01, 
  10}, {{mu, 71/48, "mu"}, 0, 3}]
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Notes**

- I have not seen code examples using `ParametricNDSolve`, `ParametricPlot3D`, and `Manipulate` so I am posting in part so others can learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important that `Manipulate` can "see" the the dependencies on the variable. There might be many ways to get this running. Here is one of them:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    x1'[t] == -(1 + x1[t]) (A[[1, 1]] x1[t] + A[[1, 2]] x2[t] + A[[1, 3]] x3[t]), 
    x2'[t] == -(1 + x2[t]) (A[[2, 1]] x1[t] + A[[2, 2]] x2[t] + A[[2, 3]] x3[t]), 
    x3'[t] == -(1 + x3[t]) (A[[3, 1]] x1[t] + A[[3, 2]] x2[t] + A[[3, 3]] x3[t]), 
    x1[0] == x10, x2[0] == x20, x3[0] == x30},
    {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]},
    {t, tmax}, {x10, x20, x30, mu}];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[sol[x10, x20, x30, mu], {t, 0, tmax}], 
 {{x10, 1, "x1"}, 0.01, 10}, 
 {{x20, 1, "x2"}, 0.01, 10}, 
 {{x30, 1, "x3"}, 0.01, 10}, 
 {{mu, 71/48, "mu"}, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Proper syntax can  be a pain.

Comment: You're welcome.