# How to plot some but not all of the solutions generated by ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parametric-functions

My question is about the syntax of plotting solutions of `ParametricNDSolve` but not all. Specifically how can I plot just $x_1,x_2,x_3$ not  $x_1,x_2,x_3,i$. My attempt is below(no error messages)

```
A = {{2, 5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1, mu}, {1, 0.5, 1}};
tmax = 100;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x1'[
      t] == -(1 + x1[t]) (A[[1, 1]] x1[t] + A[[1, 2]] x2[t] + 
        A[[1, 3]] x3[t] + e i[t]), 
    x2'[t] == -(1 + x2[t]) (A[[2, 1]] x1[t] + A[[2, 2]] x2[t] + 
        A[[2, 3]] x3[t] + e i[t]), 
    x3'[t] == -(1 + x3[t]) (A[[3, 1]] x1[t] + A[[3, 2]] x2[t] + 
        A[[3, 3]] x3[t] + e i[t]),
    i'[t] == x1[t] + x2[t] + x3[t] - i[t],
    x1[0] == x10, x2[0] == x20, x3[0] == x30, i[0] == 1},
   {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], i[t]}, {t, tmax}, {x10, x20, x30, mu, e}];
sol
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x1[x10, x20, x30, mu, e][t], x2[x10, x20, x30, mu, e][t], 
     x3[x10, x20, x30, mu, e][t]} /. sol],
  {t, 0, tmax},
  Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {X1label, X2label, X3label}, 
  BoxStyle -> Dashing[{0.02, 0.02}] , PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  AxesEdge -> {{1, 1, 1}, None, Automatic}, 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005]],
 {{x10, 1, "x1"}, 0.01, 10},
 {{x20, 1, "x2"}, 0.01, 10},
 {{x30, 1, "x3"}, 0.01, 10},
 {{mu, 71/48, "mu"}, 0, 3},
 {{e, 0.5, "e"}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Notes**

- This is in part based on code from a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175253/cant-get-parametric-ndsolve-to-work-for-three-ode-system). My question was in that previous post was answered. See the post for a previously working version for 3 odes.
- If `parametricNDSolveValue` can be used instead and solve my problem, help with the proper syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: What is A? It seems it is a matrix. `ParametricNDSolveValue` can be used.

Comment: You may try  `/. sol[[1;; 3]]]`

Comment: $A$ is a matrix. I used `ParametricNDSolveValue` previously (see link in post) put I could not get it to work. Replaced  `/.sol` with `/. sol[[1;;3]]]` it did not work, I got the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem was that you solve for `x1[t]`, `x2[t]` etc instead of `x1`, `x2` etc. Fixing that yields:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[
    {
    x1'[t]==-(1+x1[t]) (A[[1,1]] x1[t]+A[[1,2]] x2[t]+A[[1,3]] x3[t]+e i[t]),
    x2'[t]==-(1+x2[t]) (A[[2,1]] x1[t]+A[[2,2]] x2[t]+A[[2,3]] x3[t]+e i[t]),
    x3'[t]==-(1+x3[t]) (A[[3,1]] x1[t]+A[[3,2]] x2[t]+A[[3,3]] x3[t]+e i[t]),
    i'[t]==x1[t]+x2[t]+x3[t]-i[t],
    x1[0]==x10,
    x2[0]==x20,
    x3[0]==x30,
    i[0]==1
    },
    {x1,x2,x3,i},
    {t,tmax},
    {x10,x20,x30,mu,e}
];
Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot3D[
        Evaluate[Through @* (Through@{x1,x2,x3}[x10, x20, x30, mu, e]) @ t /. sol],
        {t,0,tmax},
        Ticks->None,
        PlotRange->All,
        AxesOrigin->Automatic,
        AxesLabel->{X1label,X2label,X3label},
        BoxStyle->Dashing[{0.02,0.02}],
        PlotRangePadding->None,
        AxesEdge->{{1,1,1},None,Automatic},
        AxesStyle->Thickness[0.005]
    ],
    {{x10,1,"x1"},0.01,10},
    {{x20,1,"x2"},0.01,10},
    {{x30,1,"x3"},0.01,10},
    {{mu,71/48,"mu"},0,3},
    {{e,0.5,"e"},-1,1}
]
```

[image]